# JBoss Cluster for a Web App that doesn't use EJB

Tags: jboss

Steps for JBoss Clustering 5.0.1, or 5.1.0 and also communication steps between Tomcat 5.5 and JBoss.

I  googled but no one giving exact solution for clustering of simple web application not using EJB

thanks

Comment: Hi I am new in JBoss,  I just wana know Steps for Clustering in JBoss 5.0.1                                                                  Steps means              1)how to create new node for clustering.                 2)which .XML file's need to be changed                     3) how to run different nodes                       4) how to stop diff nodes                       5) how do i know bothe node's are working.                                                                                                                                Thanks if any one just help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are so complicated. Maybe you can clarify a litle. In my undertanding, Jboss cluster is used for high availability, so your .ear or .war file will be treated equaly if you deploy EJB or not.

Maybe this could help (http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/5/html/)

Just do not configured any EJB cause you have none. 
Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Regards,

/ ADDED /

Ok i'll give you a brief but you have to read a lot of things which are related with specific configurations.

Maybe you'll need a load balancer to distribute the load along the cluster, I recomend to use Apache with mod_jk (http://community.jboss.org/wiki/usingmodjk12withjboss)

Then in the configuration of Jboss, start with the /all context, cause it have all cluster libraries, add a tag in your web.xml (distributable), add session replication config in jboss-web.xml if you need it (I assume you do), edit your /etc/hosts file if you are in linux to enable access to other hosts, enable valve ClusteredSingleSignOn if you need it for authentication, enable multicast or use a DNS, some other details you will find in the Docs.

I guess this give you a start.
Good Luck :)

Comment: hi @ RDAM  You are write  your guideline help lot... for me               thanks for your precious time